# overly complicated directory iteration structure devastating program continuity and comprehensibility

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to read in many files from a directory with an underlying substructure of the form `/train` under which there are, respectively, '`/atheism`,`/politics`,`/science` & `/sports` each containing many files. I

I need to read in all the words from all the files to create a global "dictionary", with each word in each file represented once (At this point I'm not very worried about stemming or any of that fancy stuff!).

The thing is, this complicated iteration structure that I'm using is comfusing the hell out of me whenever I try to think in a lucid way about what I have to do. How could I simplify and subdue this unwieldy beast!

```
public class FileDictCreateur 
{
    static String PATH = "/home/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/data/train";

    //the global list of all words across all articles
    static Set<String> GLOBO_DICT = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        //each of the diferent categories
        String[] categories = { "/atheism", "/politics", "/science", "/sports"};

        //cycle through all categories once to populate the global dict
        for(int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++)
        {
            String general_data_partition = PATH + categories[cycle];

            File directory = new File( general_data_partition );
            iterateDirectory( directory );
        }
    }

    private static void iterateDirectory(File directory) throws IOException 
    {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) 
        {
            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {
                iterateDirectory(directory);
            }     
            else 
            {
                System.out.println(file);

                String line; 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file ));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words

                    //here is where I will populate that 
                    //globo dict

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might make sure that you're closing your `BufferedReader` when you're done with it. If you're using Java 7+ and really want to confuse yourself, you could also take a look at [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you need a user's folder after your `/home`. Also, you could use the [`File(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Putting it together, I think you wanted something like

```
static String PATH = "Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/data/train";

// the global list of all words across all articles
static Set<String> GLOBO_DICT = new HashSet<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // each of the diferent categories
    String[] categories = { "/atheism", "/politics", "/science", "/sports" };
    File trainpath = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), PATH);
    // cycle through all categories once to populate the global dict
    for (String cycle : categories) {
        File directory = new File(trainpath, cycle);
        iterateDirectory(directory);
    }
}
```

Comment: but do I have to explicitly list the categories, cant i just iterate over the directories as i iterate over the files?

Comment: @flavius_valens IDK, can you? Are there other possible directories that shouldn't be indexed? You know your requirements, I do not.

Comment: what i mean is, is it feasible? in those directories are the terminal files only, the ones from which i want to extract the words